# Publish a npm package that is built using webpack and babeljs

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I built a very simple javascript that uses webpack for packaging and npm for publishing the project. While I am able successfully build and publish the project, I am unable to use the exported function.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/test-prod.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --display-error-details --mode production",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.28.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

Here is the webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname),
    entry: './index.js', // Entry file that will be invoked by webpack first
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'test-prod.js'
    }
};
```

Here is test function located inside 'src' folder I am planning to export:

```
export const testFunc = () => alert('Hello World!');
```

Here is the index.js:

```
const testFunc = require("./src/testFunc");

module.exports = {testFunc};
```

This is all and well. But after performing `npm publish` or `npm link`, I am unable to access the testFunc from another project.

I tried `import * as functions from 'test';`, followed by `functions.testFunc()` and `import {testFunc} from 'test';`. Both does not work.

Please let me know how to properly export a function using webpack & npm, and access it from a different project. I only need the minified javascript in my published package.

Comment: For some reason I cannot edit my own question. I am not using babel at all. It's just webpack, javascript,. and npm.

Comment: Looking at it I might try `const { testFunc } = require("./src/testFunc"); module.exports = testFunc` instead.

Comment: I made the changes, performed npm link and tried to access it from another project. Still does not work.

Comment: Could you show terminal error?

Comment: This is how I imported in another project ```import {testFunc} from 'test';```. And when I tried to invoke the function testFunc();, I got following error: 'TypeError: Object(...) is not a function'. The another project is a react web app, so this is the error I got from browser.

Comment: `npm pack` might help you inspecting what's actually inside your package by producing a local tarball of your package.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

In the webpack config file, add this

```js
    output: {
        // your current code
        library: 'test',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    }
```